# How to return the number of characters whose frequency is above a threshold

Tags: python, statistics

How do I print the number of upper case characters whose frequency is above a threshold (in the tutorial)?

The homework question is:

> Your task is to write a function which takes as input a single non-negative number and returns (not print) the number of characters in the tally whose count is strictly greater than the argument of the function. Your function should be called freq_threshold.

My answer is:

```
mobyDick = "Blah blah A　B C A RE."

def freq_threshold(threshold):
    tally = {}
    for char in mobyDick:
        if char in tally:
            tally[char] += 1
        else:
            tally[char] = 1

    for key in tally.keys():
        if key.isupper():
            print tally[key],tally.keys
            if threshold>tally[key]:return threshold
            else:return tally[key]
```

It doesn't work, but I don't know where it is wrong.

Comment: In what sense doesn't it work? Does it raise an exception? Does it print the wrong results?

Comment: Compare the return spec in your assignment ("return  the number of characters") and your return statements.

Comment: Why are you returning `threshold` whenever the frequency of a key is lower than the threshold? If the threshold is 5, and there are no upper case characters with a frequency >= 5, your function will return 5, when it should return 0. Basically, the tally seems fine, but you need to think about what results should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Your task is to return number of characters that satisfy the condition. You're trying to return count of occurrences of some character. Try this:

```
result = 0
for key in tally.keys():
  if key.isupper() and tally[key] > threshold:
    result += 1
return result
```

You can make this code more pythonic. I wrote it this way to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The part where you tally up the number of each character is fine:

```
>>> pprint.pprint ( tally )
{' ': 5,
 '.': 1,
 'A': 2,
 'B': 2,
 'C': 1,
 'E': 1,
 'R': 1,
 'a': 2,
 'b': 1,
 'h': 2,
 'l': 2,
 '\x80': 2,
 '\xe3': 1}
```

The error is in how you are summarising the tally.

- Your assignment asked you to print the *number of characters occurring more than **n** times in the string*.
- What you are returning is either ***n*** or the number of times one *particular* character occurred.

You instead need to step through your tally of characters and character counts, and *count* how many characters have frequencies exceeding ***n***.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel, but use a [counter object](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), e.g.:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> mobyDick = "Blah blah A B C A RE."
>>> c = Counter(mobyDick)
>>> c
Counter({' ': 6, 'a': 2, 'B': 2, 'h': 2, 'l': 2, 'A': 2, 'C': 1, 'E': 1, '.': 1, 'b': 1, 'R': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
def freq_threshold(s, n):
    cnt = Counter(s)
    return [i for i in cnt if cnt[i]>n and i.isupper()]
```

---

To reinvent the wheel:

```
def freq_threshold(s, n):
    d = {}
    for i in s:
        d[i] = d.get(i, 0)+1
    return [i for i in d if d[i]>n and i.isupper()]
```

Comment: Not exactly what the assignment asked for - you want the `len()` of that return list.